# Ubuntu 12.04 ethernet is not working?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, wubi, ethernet

I recently installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and have tried every method out there to get my Ethernet cable to work...unfortunately not one of the methods out there worked for me. here are some of the tests i ran:

`lspci -nnk | grep -i ethernet` gives `05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)`.

`ifconfig` gives:

```
lo Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX packets:803 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:803 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:103034 (103.0 KB) TX bytes:103034 (103.0 KB)
wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:60:6e:cd:f6:f3 
inet addr:192.168.2.101 Bcast:192.168.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::a60:6eff:fecd:f6f3/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:3130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:3156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:`1000 RX bytes:3869261 (3.8 MB) TX bytes:381110 (381.1 KB)
```

`lshw -c network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED 
description: Ethernet controller product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet vendor: Atheros Communications Inc. physical id: 0 bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0 version: 10 width: 64 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list configuration: latency=0 resources: memory:f7200000-f723ffff ioport:d000(size=128) *-network description: Wireless interface physical id: 2 bus info: usb@5:2 logical name: wlan0 serial: 08:60:6e:cd:f6:f3 capabilities: ethernet physical wireless configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=3.5.0-23-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.2.101 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The 8161 cards have been a source of many problems exactly like yours. You can find a list of posts related to the 8161 cards [here](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=AR8161). The problem seems to be related to the driver supplied in the current kernel versions; rolling back the driver seems to work for most cases. One suggested fix that apparently worked was to issue the following Terminal commands:

```
apt-cache search linux-backports-modules
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic
sudo modprobe alx
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either... any other suggestions

Comment: Run through the list of posts that I linked and try the vaariations of fixes.

Comment: thanks for your help, but  as i have mentioned before i have tried each one of them... and nothing is working...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything further to offer other than to continue searching the Interwebs for possible solutions.